# How to wrap text on bootstrap's btn-block class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What's the correct way to get bootstrap button text to wrap? I'm trying to create big buttons with fontawesome icons in them:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-block btn-color" href="#">
        <div><i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i></div>
        <div>Text that needs to wrap to next line.</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kgaopd4v/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `white-space: normal;` to the `.btn` class.

More information about white-space:

- [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)
- [The CSS white-space Property Explained](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/)